# What happened to the rest of the Academy class?

Tags: naruto

In Naruto, when the academy classes are shown in the beginning, there are characters who appear who do not appear as genin later, as far as I can tell. The two characters in the second row on the right don't seem to show up later. What happens to these characters? Naruto is presented as one of the only characters to repeatedly fail, so are these characters who passed and then just never showed up again, or do they drop out of becoming ninjas?

[image: Academy class]

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Students graduating from the academy are given an additional test by their Jonin sensei. Kakashi mentioned during the bell test that only about 33% students pass this test, and those who fail are sent back to the Academy.

[image: Kakashi's bell test]

Among the other students in Naruto's class, some may have taken up a different profession after failing the Jonin test a few times, while others may have passed the test and taken up work as genins. Konoha does get a lot of genin mission requests, not just the plot relevant ones involving main characters.