# Does every ninja become a jonin?

Tags: naruto

In Naruto, a number of ninjas have become jonin, such as Neji and Kakashi. Does every ninja who becomes a chunin by definition become a jonin if they live long enough, or do some remain a chunin forever?

Comment: Iraku is still a Chuunin and likely to stay a Chuunin.

Comment: @Nil I believe you meant Iruka not Iraku. There is, to my knowledge, no such character.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

No not everyone will become a Jonin. As you may have noticed, some ninja like Naruto don't even become Chuunin. Naruto is a rare example however.

In order to become a jonin, a ninja must be extremely skilled. Jōnin are generally able to use at least two types of elemental chakra, some genjutsu, and above average taijutsu skills.

They are usually also appointed to A and/or S ranked missions alone while those under the Jonin rank usually go with a team, or not at all.

Comment: Was about to say something about the second line but the third kinda held it up..

Comment: Awww but you didn't mention the Eternal Genin!!!

And Naruto wasn't a real genin since Shippuden, it's just that no one bothered to go "*Poof* You're a chuunin now, here's your vest"

Comment: If they held a Chuunin exam for him, the opponents will all surrender before fighting him, unless its people like Konohamaru.

Comment: There are people who are joked at forever being genin (might be filler only though). In the War, there was the fight between the previous mizukage, where the ninja fighting him were incredibly stupid and unable to comprehend that he was an illusion. Their only non taijutsu attacks were throwing weapons, which they had to throw and regather several times before Gaara stepped in.

Answer (score 5):

If you think about this from a real world military viewpoint, it is like asking if every recruit becomes a commanding officer. The answer is **no**. Also as related, keep in mind that not all [academy students become Chūnin](https://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/3536/what-happened-to-the-rest-of-the-academy-class), so that might apply here too.

And as per the [wiki](http://naruto.wikia.com/wiki/J%C5%8Dnin)

> It is as of yet unknown what one has to undergo to become one. It is
>   mentioned that jōnin are appointed, however there was mention of a
>   Jōnin Exam in the anime's Kurama Clan Arc. When a ninja becomes a
>   jōnin, they may be assigned a three-man genin team to supervise.

And then there is also this guy.. [Kosuke Maruboshi](http://naruto.wikia.com/wiki/Kosuke_Maruboshi) who *even though by choice*, has been a genin for over 50 years. This could also apply to your question.

Answer (score 1):

Some become Chunin, some become Jonin. No one knows how they become Jonin, but in the Anime both appointments and exams are mentioned as a way to become Jonin. Only power- and skillful ninja will become Jonin.

Answer (score 1):

I know it's like a ranking. You have to undergo an exam or a test to be one ranking higher...
I don't know if this sequence is correct: genin, chuunin, jonin...
In the 1st episode of naruto shippuuden, it is known that naruto is the only one that's still a genin, others were chuunin and jonin.
There are other ninjas that maybe are still on the same level or ranking.