# At the end, did Naruto skip Chunnin and Jounin rank before becoming Hokage?

Tags: naruto

In chapter 700 of Naruto manga (last chapter) it was shown that [Uzumaki Naruto](http://naruto.wikia.com/wiki/Naruto_Uzumaki) finally reached his dream of becoming Hokage. It was also shown that he didn't achieve it immediately after the 4th Shinobi War ended as [Hatake Kakashi](http://naruto.wikia.com/wiki/Kakashi_Hatake) was the 6th Hokage and Naruto was the 7th.

AFAIK, even when fighting [Otsutsuki Kaguya](http://naruto.wikia.com/wiki/Kaguya_%C5%8Ctsutsuki), Naruto was a Genin as he never passed the Chuunin nor Jounin exam (as far as the manga is concerned). There is an anime where [Naruto took the Chuunin exam](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=l1eWFKjFdtU), but he failed after disqualified due to using Sage Mode.

It was shown in Naruto the Movie "Road to Ninja", that to become Jounin, one must become a Chuunin first. However it is also to be noted that [double promotion is also possible](https://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/19371/is-it-possible-for-a-genin-to-become-a-jonin/19479#19479).

4th, 5th, and 6th Hokage were all Jounin prior to being Hokage. I'm not sure about the 1st, 2nd, and 3rd Hokage, although strength-wise they are stronger than your average Jounin. The [next Hokage](http://naruto.wikia.com/wiki/Hokage) was chosen either by the current Hokage, or the Daimyou of the Land of Fire. No other requirements was listed on the Wikia.

So, to the question, has Naruto reached the rank of Jounin when he was selected as the 7th Hokage? Or was he still a Genin, since it didn't actually matter much considering that everyone knows who he is, that he was the hero who saved Konoha from Pain, and more importantly the world from Infinite Tsukuyomi.

Comment: Yes, he took at least the Chunin exam. I don't remember the episode but it was shown that he was studying and working hard for the written part of the Chunin exam.

Comment: Taking the exam and passing it is a different matter. I already mentioned that he did took a Chuunin exam, and failed since he broke the rule.

Comment: That was a filler. but in this one, it did not show the actual exam it was just indicating that Naruto did not skip or use any shortcut to achieve his goal.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

> In regards to Naruto's rank which remains as the lowest one, Genin, due to Naruto spending most of his Part II's time fighting and training, Kishimoto decided Naruto would skip the following ranks to become the Hokage, which he felt was appealing.

Taken from [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Naruto_Uzumaki), which references  [Cinema Today: "Boruto: Naruto the Movie" (in Japanese)](https://www.cinematoday.jp/page/A0004639).

Answer (score 2):

The thing that he studied for the written test was a very long time ago. Don't forget that he did take the exam as a kid but it got cut short by orochimaru and only shikamaru got promoted.

TBH Naruto didn't need to; Kakashi admitted that he had already surpassed all the past Hokages and he saved all the villages. If he takes the Chunin exam he would be way too overadvantaged over everyone.

The chunin exam only tests the abilty, and naruto has shown that he has a lot more than the capability of any chunin or jounin. He didn't need the exam.

Answer (score 0):

While it is true that we never see him get promoted even to chuunin, notice that in one of the episodes after the end of the fight between him and Sasuke (around Shippuuden 490), Kakashi tells him that he would be promoted to jounin after studying hard for it, since Naruto already proved that he had enough strength and skill, but lacked knowledge.

We're shown that he became Hokage, but we're not shown that he finally became a jounin. Maybe I've skipped something though.

Comment: "but we're not shown that he finally became a jounin"

Because he never became a jounin.